# update website asynchronous using REST API

Tags: python, node.js, rest

I want to make a website which gets the data from a REST API and use it to update my website asynchronously for every 10 seconds. How can I do that? I want to know the ways either for Nodejs or python.

In nodejs, I have come across socket.io but I need to create a separate file to start a server and listen to it and client which connect to the server and he will get the updates. But this is the optimized solution to this problem.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Request = require("request");

var data = "";
Request.get("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/709694/feeds.json?api_key=MY_API_KEY&results=1",(error,response,body)=>{
    if(error){
      return console.dir(error);
    }
    data = JSON.parse(body);
});
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Patient Monitoring & Diagnostics',data:data});
});

module.exports = router;
```

The above code is Nodejs code. I want to run the `Request.get()` for every 10 seconds and update the webpage without refreshing it.

Comment: In order to solicit a better response, you should post what code you've tried, where you've looked etc. In absence of that I'd suggest looking up the `fetch` api in the browser, as well as the `http` module in nodejs.

Comment: i have updated the question

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setInterval`

Wrap your `Request.get` with function and invoke it with every 10 seconds.

```
const apiRequest = () => {
    Request.get("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/709694/feeds.json?api_key=MY_API_KEY&results=1",(error,response,body)=>{
    if(error){
      return console.dir(error);
    }
    data = JSON.parse(body);
    });
}

setTimeout(apiRequest, 10000);
```

And if you have no exact reason for using `nodejs Request`,

Considering client-side api request with `axios`, and `state` change with `react` would also be a good option.

Comment: How can I update the webpage without refreshing the page

Comment: @SaiPavan Using axios or ajax would update your webpage without refreshing the page. It only updates partial view. Use client-side api call if you are trying to update your page without refreshing

Comment: suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516798/client-side-vs-server-side-when-get-data-from-api as if you want to understand the routine.

Comment: Thanks, @koo. I did it.

Comment: @SaiPavan Good for you! If your issue has succesfully been solved, please adopt the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the solution to the problem. Thanks to @koo

```
  const apiRequest = () => {
    const url = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/709694/feeds.json?api_key=MY_API_KEY&results=1'; 

    $.ajax({url:url,success:function(result){
        let field1 = result.feeds[0].field1;
        $(".div1 p").text(field1);

    }});
}

setInterval(apiRequest, 10000);
```